# Splitting Excel file but retaining lookup data and formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a master expenses file that has a page for each employee summarising their expenses.  The employee sheets run off a hidden data sheets.

I want to send each employee a copy of their expenses with the lookups etc hidden but still in tact so that they can complete the coding etc using lookup lists like project and expense codes from the data sheets.

What I envisage is a macro create to a set of individual employee files with only their page but with the lookups and data in each remaining in tact and hidden.  I've been trying to create a macro to systematically work through the file creating new files for each employee deleting each of the other employee sheets but retaining the hidden data and related lookups - with no success

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Would having the data sheet exist on a different file in a different network location be a solution?

Comment: I don't think so, I need the employees to use the lookups etc offline

Comment: Maybe a completely different approach is to disable all tabs but one. You distribute the whole Excel file, but they can only see/edit one page. Don't know how to do that though.